# Import slide from Sharepoint to directly in powerpoint

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I was trying to import a PowerPoint slide from a SharePoint folder, when I click on button it should add the selected file in current active powerpoint.

But below mentioned script it's not working, can anyone help me on this.

```
Sub ImportFileFromSharePoint()

    'Declare variables
    Dim strSharePointURL As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim pptPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation

    'Get the SharePoint URL and file name
    strSharePointURL = "https://gep1.sharepoint.com/:p:/r/sites/Trial153/_layouts/15/Doc.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B80371DF3-593A-4707-9291-A6208C4E17F3%7D&file=WorldMap.pptx"
    strFileName = "WorldMap.pptx"

    'Download the file from SharePoint
    Dim http As Object
    Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    http.Open "GET", strSharePointURL, False
    http.send

    'Save the downloaded file to a temporary location
    Dim tempFilePath As String
    tempFilePath = Environ("TEMP") & "\" & strFileName
    Dim fileStream As Object
    Set fileStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    fileStream.Open
    fileStream.Type = 1 'Binary
    fileStream.Write http.responseBody
    fileStream.SaveToFile tempFilePath
    fileStream.Close

    'Open the PowerPoint presentation
    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
    Set pptPresentation = pptApp.Presentations.Open(tempFilePath)

    'Add your slide manipulation code here, e.g., pptPresentation.Slides.Add, etc.

    'Close the PowerPoint presentation and quit the application
    pptPresentation.Close
    pptApp.Quit

    'Clean up
    Set pptPresentation = Nothing
    Set pptApp = Nothing

    'Delete the temporary file
    Kill tempFilePath


'Run the code
ImportFileFromSharePoint

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "not working" is not a very useful description of what happens when you run your code.  What does it do or not do and how is that different from what you want?